# Grouped Stacked Bar Chart in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

Is it possible to create a bar chart like this one where the bar chart is split with one group falling below the axis and one group falling above it? Also would it be possible for those bars to be stacked, split on a different field?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I got for a dual bar chart is like this:

Choose visualization as Aggregation Based.

Metrics - Y Axis Aggregation as sum
Buckets - X Axis Aggregation Terms, your custom term
Buckets - Split Chart - Rows - Sub Aggregation: Terms, your custom term